# actiondispatch cookieoverflow post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, cookies, session-cookies

I have a form in which I add custom html in body of form(By JS). When I add like 20 objects(3 input fields in a row), I get rails error i.e.

ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow

It occur sometimes, sometimes it dont. I dont the main reason behind this. 
The request is POST.

Comment: I don't think that the error is showing because of appending the form with custom html! Probably you are using cookies in your app and the content that you are trying to store is bigger than that limit(4kb).

Answer (score 4):

I got the cause for this behavior. Actually, the flash messages are saved in cookies by rails. So when we send post request, like in my case I sent many data which will all first validate and then error messages will be added to flash. Now for those 20 objects, error messages were also 20(actually more than 20). That's why cookie were overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when I tried to display the **flash messages** with tons of errors. My solution was change to `ActiveRecord::SessionStore`
You can find the docs here
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/SessionStore.html